# Html attribute with echo

Tags: php, html, echo

I have the next html element:

```
<div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 20%;"><? echo $pass; ?></div>
```

Now, I want that the width element would changed according to my echo element .

I try to do the next:

```
 <div class="bar bar-success" style=<? echo $pass; ?>/<? echo $fail; ?>%;><? echo $pass; ?></div>
```

But it doesn't work. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help....

```
<div class="bar bar-success" style="width: <?php echo round($pass/$fail); ?>%"><?php echo $pass; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bar bar-success" style="<?= round($pass/$fail); ?>%"><? echo $pass; ?></div>
```

I used [`round()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) so you always get a whole number.

Comment: I try to get the value of witdh, according to ration between the $pass and the $fail values ($pass  divided by $fail)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bar bar-success" style="width: <?php echo round($pass / $fail) . '%'; ?>"><?php echo $pass; ?></div>
```

You're forgetting quotes around the `style` attribute and forgot to set the `width` so lets say `$pass` was `4` and `$fail` was `2`, you would be left with:

```
<div class="bar bar-success" style=2%;>4</div>
```